# Из jQuery в чистый JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

В jQuery есть достаточно простая возможность по клику на объект получить его порядковый index из N-числа аналогичных объектов:

```js
$('.paragraph').click(function() {
  const Num = $(this).index();
  console.log(Num);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="paragraph">1</p>
<p class="paragraph">2</p>
<p class="paragraph">3</p>
<p class="paragraph">4</p>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как на чистом JS реализовать этот же функционал и на сколько массивней получится код.
Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.paragraph').forEach((el, index) => {
    el.addEventListener('click', () => {
        console.log(index + 1);
    });
});
```

```html
<p class="paragraph">1</p>
<p class="paragraph">2</p>
<p class="paragraph">3</p>
<p class="paragraph">4</p>
```

На самом деле индекс должен начинаться с нуля. Но ради "совместимости" тут сделано с 1

Comment: Спасибо, отработало, но все же я убрал увеличение значения на "1" перед выводом, так как при каждой последующей итерации, значение продолжает увеличиваться на "1", а мне необходимо сохранение индекса объекта вне зависимости от кол-ва нажатий на него.

Comment: @Максим да, заменил на index + 1

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае [`.index`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) возвращает индекс элемента в родителе.

Таким образом нужно получить родителя элемента, например с помощью метода [`.parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode)

И пройтись по всем дочерним элементам, пока не дойдем до искомого.

Получить соседний элемент можно с помощью метода [`.nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/nextElementSibling)

```js
function index(el) {
  if (!el.parentNode) return -1;

  var parent = el.parentNode;

  for (var cur = parent.firstElementChild, index = 0; cur && (cur != el); cur = cur.nextElementSibling, index++);

  return index;
}
$('.paragraph').click(function() {
  const Num = index(this);
  console.log(Num);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p class="paragraph">1</p>
  <p class="paragraph">2</p>
  <p class="paragraph">3</p>
  <p class="paragraph">4</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ниже приведена наиболее точная интерпретация вашего кода на `JQuery`. Во первых `.index()` возвращает индекс элемента в родителе (и он теоретичеки может и изменится при удалении/добавлении элементов, поэтому определять его нужно именно внутри обработчика). Во вторых `this` внутри обработчика события ссылается на элемент к которому это событие непосредственно привязано. В третих, для поиска индекса элемента проще использовать встроенный в `Array` метод `.indexOf()`.

```js
window.document.querySelectorAll('.paragraph').forEach((el) => {
  el.addEventListener('click', (event) => {

    var index = window.Array.prototype.indexOf.call(el.parentNode.children, el) + 1;
    console.log(index);

  });
});
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="paragraph">1</p>
  <p class="paragraph">2</p>
  <p class="paragraph">3</p>
  <p class="paragraph">4</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Писать `window` не обязательно. Потому что это ключ самого `window`, то есть вы лишнее действие `window.window` делаете.

Comment: @Pavel Grishaev я знаю, что это не обязательно в глобальном контексте. Это интерпетация, и здесь показано, что во что вложено.